Probability that points are placed in certain subsets of a grid
Consider $X,Y\in\mathbb{N}$  and  the set $\{1,\ldots,X\}\times\{1,\ldots,Y\}$. Moreover, let $0.25\geq c>\alpha>0$ and consider $cXY$ randomly placed distinct points $s_1,\ldots,s_{cXY}$, i.e. one takes a subset with cardinality $cXY$ of the grid uniformly at random. Independently from the $s_i$, we also consider random points $g_1,\ldots,g_{cXY}$ on the grid with the same uniform distribution.
Question:
Given subsets $G_1,G_2\subseteq\{1,\ldots,X\}\times\{1,\ldots,Y\}$ with $|G_1|=|G_2|=\alpha XY$, what is the probability that there exists some $i\in\{1,\ldots,cXY\}$ such that $s_i\in G_1$ and $g_i\in G_2$? Moreover, how fast does this probability go to $1$ when $n$ goes to infinity? (Obviously, one needs to slightly change $\alpha$ and $c$ when changing $n$. However, one can ensure that $\alpha\geq \alpha^*>0,c\geq c^*>0$).
My progress:
Using permutations, and the notation $n=X\cdot Y$ and $A=\{1,\ldots,\alpha n\}$, the question is equivalent to obtaining the probability that for two random subsets $S$ and $G$ with cardinality $cn$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ we have that $S\cap G\cap A\neq\emptyset$. Using some combinatorics and the law of total probability, I ended up with (I used the complementary event):
\begin{align*}
    &\sum\limits_{S\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\},|S|=cn} P(S\cap G \cap A=\emptyset)\frac{1}{\binom{n}{cn}}\\
    &=\sum\limits_{S\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\},|S|=cn} \frac{1}{\binom{n}{cn}}\frac{(n-|S\cap A|)!((1-c)n)!}{n!((1-c)n-|S\cap A|)!}\\
    &=\frac{1}{\binom{n}{cn}}\frac{((1-c)n)!}{n!}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\alpha n}\frac{(n-i)!}{((1-c)n-i)!}\binom{\alpha n}{i}\binom{(1-\alpha)n}{cn-i}.
\end{align*}
Applying Stirling's formula to the factorials, I can bound the expression from above by
$d\cdot n^b\left(p^n+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\alpha  n-1}\left(\frac{c^c(1-c)^{2(1-c)}(1-\frac{i}{n})^{(1-\frac{i}{n})}\alpha^{\alpha}(1-\alpha)^{(1-\alpha)}}{(1-c-\frac{i}{n})^{1-c-\frac{i}{n}}(\frac{i}{n})^{\frac{i}{n}}(\alpha-\frac{i}{n})^{\alpha-\frac{i}{n}}(c-\frac{i}{n})^{c-\frac{i}{n}}(1-\alpha-c+\frac{i}{n})^{1-\alpha-c+\frac{i}{n}}}\right)^n\right)$ for constants $d,b,p$ with $0<p<1$ which are independent of $n$ and this holds as long as $\alpha\geq\alpha^*>0$ and $c\geq c^*>0$. Each summand (without the exponent $n$) then takes the form $\frac{c^c(1-c)^{2(1-c)}(1-b)^{1-b}\alpha^{\alpha}(1-\alpha)^{1-\alpha}}{(1-c-b)^{1-c-b}b^{b}(\alpha-b)^{\alpha-b}(c-b)^{c-b}(1-\alpha-c+b)^{1-\alpha-c+b}}$ for some $0<b<\alpha$. One can show that, as a function $g(\cdot,\alpha,c)$ of $b$, i.e. $\alpha$ and $c$ are fixed, the maximum is attained at $b^*(\alpha,c)=\frac{1-c}{2}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{1-c}{2}\right)^2+\alpha c\frac{c-1}{c+1}}$. Moreover, by looking at the graphs on GeoGebra, it  holds that this maximum, i.e. $g(b^*)$ increases with decreasing $\alpha$ and $c$. If one could prove this, it would suffice to show that $g(b^*)<1$ for any $\alpha$ and $c$ because then the probability would be bounded by $d\cdot n^b(p^n+\alpha n\cdot g(b^*(a^*,c^*),a^*,c^*)^n)$ which goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.
I could already show that for fixed $\alpha$ and $c$, $g(\cdot,\alpha,c)$ can never be larger than $1$ by applying Stirling's approximation and the fact that probabilities are bounded by $1$. Moreover, since $b^*$ is the unique maximum, this is the only point where $g$ could attain $1$. However, this does not seem to be the case.
Does anyone have an idea how to complete the proof, i.e. showing that $g(b^*,\alpha,c)<1$ for any $\alpha$ and $c$ and that $g(b^*,\alpha,c)$ is increasing when $\alpha$ and $c$ decrease?
I would also be grateful for other ways to prove the asympotics of the considered probability.
